# Почему джанго выдает ошибку в данной строке

Tags: django, backend, python-3.7

есть urls файл, в нем вот такая запись

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MovieView.as_view()) 
    path('<int:pk>/', views.MovieView.as_view())
]
```

вылетает ошибка в строке `path('<int:pk>/', views.MovieView.as_view())`

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Эта страка указывает на вот этот класс

```
class MovieDatailView(View):
    """Полное описание фильма"""
    def get(self, request, pk):
        movie = Movie.objects.get(id = pk)
        return render(request, "movies/movie_datail.html", {"movie": movie})
```

Возникло два вопроса, почему возникает ошибка в данной строке и что делает метод as.view()?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax не может возникать из-за того что у вас нет запятой в urlpatterns?

Comment: Потому что по синтаксису python элементы списка отделяются запятыми, а у вас запятых в списке urlpatterns нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MovieView.as_view()), #запятую забыл
    path('<int:pk>/', views.MovieView.as_view())
]
```

и почему у тебя в views MovieDetailView, а в urls MovieView?